# Mathematica's algorithm for FindIndependentEdgeSet?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

Documentation does not mention about algorithm. My guess is Blossom algorithm because I do not know of any better one.

Posting it with hope that someone might know it for sure.

Comment: this is one of the biggest issues I have with WRI. They never post the source of the algorithm in the documentation, which should be there ethically. If you check Matlab's documentation the source and references are clearly mentioned.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask. Ask Wolfram Support.

Comment: However, what would you gain in practice by knowing in this case? The matching problem is well defined. Solutions are easy to verify. What difference does it make which algorithm is used to solve it?  I completely agree that in many cases it is useful, or even critical, to know how a function works. But I do not see why that would be the case here.

Comment: All that said, IGraph/M includes `IGMaximumMatching`, which uses an implementation of blossom from LEMON graph, and is slightly faster than `FindIndependentEdgeSet`.

Comment: I am documenting the functions available in different languages for finding maximum matching and I wanted to add as much details to them as possible. I have implemented blossom's algorithm as well and I do not need to know algorithm to find maximum matching. But that is not why I am asking. Thanks for pointing to IGraph/M implementation.

Comment: I think that's entirely reasonable—one good reason I did not think of. Will you share your findings? In this case, IGraph/M is using LEMON directory, so the credit goes to LEMON https://lemon.cs.elte.hu